# Constexpr check if static_cast of pointers between two hierarchically related types changes the pointer value

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, static-cast

For some specialised allocator-like thing I'm implementing, I would like to require that all objects that are going to be stored share a common base class as their first subobject. This allows me to keep a single pointer the common base class as both an indicator of the start of the object as well as to regain access to the original object using `static_cast`, assuming I have some way to know the type of the original object.

Specifically, I would like the following equality to always hold for any pointer `ptr`
to a type `Base`, assuming no virtual inheritance between `Derived` and `Base`.

```
reinterpret_cast<char *>(static_cast<Derived*>(ptr)) == reinterpret_cast<char *>(ptr)
```

I assume that this equation holds either for all valid pointers of a given class hierarchy,
or it doesn't hold for any valid pointer of a given class hierarchy. Is that correct?

Therefore, that check should be possible to be made at compile-time, without even knowing the runtime value of `ptr`. So is there a `constexpr` method to check if a `static_cast` between two related types changes the pointer value? The above equality seems not acceptable, as I found no constexpr way to create test pointer.

Comment: i dont understand the question. If they all inherit from a common base class then why is any of this needed? And even with the casts, why no `dynamic_cast` ?

Comment: is your question: How to determine if `Base` is the first base class of some type `T` ? ?

Comment: my question is how to determine at compile time if the given equality will be true or false. I am pretty sure that this is the same as to determine at compile time if the path from `T` to `Base` passes only through first base classes along the hierarchy.

Comment: `dynamic_cast` is not an option because this is for small embedded systems without RTTI.

Comment: That will only work for standard layout classes. Then https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_layout_compatible with the base class could help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking about is pointer interconvertibility. There is a related trait [`std::is_pointer_interconvertible_base_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_pointer_interconvertible_base_of) which isn't implemented yet in gcc and clang. See also [the paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0466r5.pdf) and [issue](https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/273). Pointer interconvertible types have the same address and their pointers can be casted between with `reinterpret_cast`.

> I assume that this equation holds either for all valid pointers of a given class hierarchy, or it doesn't hold for any valid pointer of a given class hierarchy. Is that correct?

As you already noted, virtual inheritance foils this, but so does failure of the standard layout criteria. If `Derived` has multiple base classes, and `Base` isn't the first, it fails.

The question fails to motivate the requirement for having the same address. If that is not a requirement, `static_cast` to upcast from `Derived` to `Base` and to downcast from `Base` to `Derived` will *just work* so long as the inheritance relationship is not virtual, unambiguous, and public.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! The reason for the requirement is to allow a single pointer to be used as both reference to the object and delimiter of (one side of) the memory extent of the object - to reduce memory overhead.